# Keeping track if an item is a favorite with core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I use core data to display a favorites collection view. User taps add to favorite button and that text on the collection view cells text view goes to core data. Now i can add the same item to the favorites list twice. But i want to change that. I have created a Boolean attribute in core data called `isFavorite` to keep track if that item is in the favorites list or not. But i have no idea where to go from here. This is the code i use when user taps to add to favorite button and save the data to core data

```
@IBAction func favoriteBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let task = MyJokes(context: context)
        task.favoriteJokes = textView.text!
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
}
```

Comment: isFavorite is not required. You can save the item when he clicked on favorite and remove on unfavorite. So at the end, you can find all favorite item from core data.

Comment: Yeah there is no problem with that. I need to find a way to block when user tries to add an item to favorites that already is in favorites

Comment: @IBAction func favoriteBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton){
          if ([sender isSelected]) {
                    [sender setSelected: NO];
                     //**Add Item**
                } 
 }  // You can use this way